# Как в Pyqt5 при нажатии на кнопку закрыть окно и открыть другое

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Пишу свою первую игру на *PyQt5*. 
Уже готово главное меню, только вот никак не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку к примеру "Начать игру" у меня закрывалось меню и начиналась собственно сама игра.

Точнее пробовал разными способами, но каждый раз получал ошибку:

> QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running.

Вот мой код:

```py
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as p
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap,QFont,QPainter
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtMultimedia



class Main(p.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,name1='Начать игру',name2='Продолжить',name3='Настройки',name4='Выход',fil = 'menu.jpg',mus = 'mentheme.mp3'):
        super().__init__()
        box = p.QHBoxLayout()
        pixmap = QPixmap('%s/data/images/%s' % (sys.path[0],fil))
        lbl = p.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        box.addWidget(lbl)
        self.but1 = p.QPushButton(name1,lbl)
        self.but2 = p.QPushButton(name2,lbl)
        self.but3 = p.QPushButton(name3,lbl)
        self.but4 = p.QPushButton(name4,lbl)
        
        self.but1.move(100,650)
        self.but2.move(400,650)
        self.but3.move(700,650)
        self.but4.move(1000,650)
        
        self.but1.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but2.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but3.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but4.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        
        self.but1.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but2.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but3.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but4.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        
        self.but1.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but2.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but3.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but4.setFixedSize(250,70)
        
        self.path = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('%s/data/music/%s' % (sys.path[0],mus))
        self.media = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.path) 
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.media)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.player.play()
        
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.but4.clicked.connect(quit)

        
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    
class Win(Main):
    def __init__(self,name1,name2,name3,name4,fil,mus):
        super().__init__(name1,name2,name3,name4,fil,mus)

class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Icons:
    pass

class Video:
    pass


def start_game():
    pass

def setting():
    pass

def quit():
    sys.exit()

def cont_game():
    pass


app = p.QApplication(sys.argv)
r = Main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я отметит те строки, которые изменил, добавил, удалил. Если будут вопросы, напишите и я прокомментирую. Я поставил свое изображение и музыку, не забудете заменит на свою.

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as p
import sys,os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap,QFont,QPainter
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtMultimedia


class Main(p.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name1='Начать игру',
                       name2='Продолжить',
                       name3='Настройки',
                       name4='Выход',
                       fil = 'menu.jpg',
                       mus = 'mentheme.mp3'):
        super().__init__()

        box = p.QHBoxLayout(self)                                       # +++ self
#        pixmap = QPixmap('%s/data/images/%s' % (sys.path[0],fil))
        pixmap = QPixmap('ball.png')

        lbl = p.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        box.addWidget(lbl)
        self.but1 = p.QPushButton(name1,lbl)
        self.but2 = p.QPushButton(name2,lbl)
        self.but3 = p.QPushButton(name3,lbl)
        self.but4 = p.QPushButton(name4,lbl)

        self.but1.move(100, 650)
        self.but2.move(400, 650)
        self.but3.move(700, 650)
        self.but4.move(1000,650)

        self.but1.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but2.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but3.setStyleSheet('Background:red')
        self.but4.setStyleSheet('Background:red')

        self.but1.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but2.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but3.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))
        self.but4.setFont(QFont('Arial',20))

        self.but1.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but2.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but3.setFixedSize(250,70)
        self.but4.setFixedSize(250,70)

#        self.path = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('%s/data/music/%s' % (sys.path[0],mus))
        self.path = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('D:/_Qt/Mp3/zvuki_prirody-td.wav')

        self.media = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.path) 
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.media)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.player.play()

        self.showFullScreen()
        self.but4.clicked.connect(quit)


# ?        sys.exit(app.exec_())


class Win(Main):
#    def __init__(self, name1, name2, name3, name4, fil,mus):
#        super().__init__(name1, name2, name3, name4, fil,mus)

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.but1.clicked.connect(self.goGeme)

    def goGeme(self):
        msg = p.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Game', 'Игра началась!' )

# + ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Icons:
    pass


class Video:
    pass


def start_game():
    pass

def setting():
    pass

def quit():
    sys.exit()

def cont_game():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":                  # +++
    app = p.QApplication(sys.argv)
    r = Win()                               # - Main()
    r.show()                                # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())                   # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Я изменил ваш метод goGeme так,чтобы он открывал окно где у меня в будет сама игра и закрывал главное меню

```
def goGeme(self): 
    self.close(); 
    msg = p.QWidget(); 
    but = p.QPushButton('Hello',msg); 
    msg.show(); 
    sys.exit(app.exec_());
```

> только вот это окно после появления сразу исчезало,а когда попробовал добавить app.exec_() снова появилась ошибка QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running.Что я делаю не так?

---

Сделайте `msg` атрибутом класса `self.msg`

```
...
def goGeme(self):
    #  msg = p.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Game', 'Игра началась!' )
    self.hide()                             # close(); 
    self.msg = p.QWidget();                 # self.
    but = p.QPushButton('Hello', self.msg); 
    self.msg.show(); 
    # sys.exit(app.exec_());                # ---
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я изменил ваш метод goGeme так,чтобы он открывал окно где у меня в будет сама игра и закрывал главное меню ```def goGeme(self):
        self.close();
        msg = p.QWidget();
        but = p.QPushButton('Hello',msg);
        msg.show();
        sys.exit(app.exec_());``` только вот это окно после появления сразу исчезало,а когда попробовал добавить app.exec_() снова появилась ошибка QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running.Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Gor смотрите добавление в ответе